# MYSQL Records not found

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have imported a CSV into MYSQL. It all worked fine and i can see the records fine through PHPMYADMIN and through the console. But when i search for a record that i know is there, it isnt finding it.

Query is basically -

```
SELECT * from `companies` where `name` = 'test'; <--- I corrected this because all the answers are talking about the query. The problem isnt with the query. Please read my update following.
```

But once i manually edit that column and save, the same query finds it fine.

I have tried to TRIM the column but it isnt making any difference.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: The issue isn't with the query. The query works fine once I manually edit the record and save it. So i think it has to do with returns or non-ASCII characters in the record itself or a collation issue.

Comment: wrap test in single quote and try again.

Comment: SELECT * from companies where name = 'test';

Comment: backticks are only for escaping column or table names!

Comment: SELECT * from companies where name LIKE 'test';

Comment: solved your issue?

Comment: I am using PHPMYADMIN to generate the search, i.e using the GUI.

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM  `accounts` 
WHERE  `company` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 'TEST'
USING latin1 ) 
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: The record exists but the query isnt finding it.

Answer (score 0):

This will find word 'test' in your `name` column so extra spaces will not effect your result but this is wild searching so it will match also words like 'testing', 'this is test' etc so if you want exactly match with particular word like 'test' you can't use this but you can check result with this query. If you getting your result using this query it means there are extra spaces in your column value.

```
SELECT * from companies where name LIKE %test%;
```

Comment: An explanation about the code would improve your answer drastically.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Using the wildcard does work which confirms there are extra spaces. How to i TRIM the spaces? I tried `UPDATE companies SET name = TRIM(name);`

Comment: Your update query is right it should work. There must be any other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove BackTicks for the value test

```
SELECT * from companies where name = "test";
```